# how to locate dynamic elements in `protractor`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, protractor

I get this error when I try to run the code below:

> Failed: element not visible

Following is the html code for the elements I want to locate:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle ng-binding ng-scope" aria-expanded="false"    
role="button" href="/" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-if="tab.subtabs">
Content
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu ng-scope" role="menu" ng-if="tab.subtabs">
<li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="test in tab.subtabs">
<a class="ng-binding" target="_self" href="/custom/ui">Custom</a>
</li>
<li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="test in tab.subtabs">
<a class="ng-binding" target="_self" href="/patch/ui">Patch</a></li>
<li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="test in tab.subtabs">
<a class="ng-binding" target="_self" href="/swd/ui">Software</a>
```

I want to click on element within the tags:

```
<a class="ng-binding" target="_self" href="/custom/ui">Custom</a>
<a class="ng-binding" target="_self" href="/patch/ui">Patch</a>
<a class="ng-binding" target="_self" href="/swd/ui">Software</a>
```

I have tried following code in `protractor`, but it is not working:

```
it("should click on Content and then custom", function(){
    element(by.xpath('/html/body/bf-header/div/nav/div/div/div[2]/ul[1]  
   /li[2]/a')).element(by.xpath('/html/body/bf-header/div/nav/div/div   
   /div[2]/ul[1]/li[3]/ul/li[1]')).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

> `element(by.xpath('/html/body/bf-header/div/nav/div/div/div[2]/ul[1]
>
>      /li[2]/a')).element(by.xpath('/html/body/bf-header/div/nav/div/div
>
>      /div[2]/ul[1]/li[3]/ul/li[1]')).click();`

Well, now you can probably see why the [Protractor Style Guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#never-use-xpath) recommends not to ever use XPath location technique:

> *NEVER use xpath*
>
> Why?
>
> - It's the slowest and most brittle locator strategy of all
> - Markup is
>     very easily subject to change and therefore xpath locators require a
>     lot of maintenance
> - xpath expressions are unreadable and very hard to
>     debug

It is not always true and, if you choose XPath, the expressions you make must at least really be simple and readable. The first thing to fix, if you are gonna stay with XPaths, is not to make absolute XPath expressions - you don't have to start with `html` element and check every single element going down the tree to the desired element.

---

In this case, simple "by link text" or "by partial link text" locators should work perfectly:

```
element(by.linkText("Custom")).click();
```

Note that the `Failed: element not visible` error might be thrown, because you don't click the menu to open it up, before trying to click the submenu (assuming these are the submenu links you need to click).

You might also need to *wait for the element to be clickable*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var custom = element(by.linkText("Custom"));

browser.wait(Ec.elementToBeClickable(custom), 5000);
custom.click();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @alexce,Ok, I have tried to use above mentioned solution, but now I see the following error:

 Failed: No element found using locator: By.linkText("Content")

I also added the following to try to slow down the protractor but it still zips through really fast and I suppose that could be causing the error I am seeing now. If that is true, how do I slow it down:
             
 browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40000);
 element(by.linkText('Content')).click();

"Content" is the parent link that opens the new window when clicked on, which has the other children links such as "Custom".

Comment: @alexce, here is another strange thing. I can find the element when I try to look for it using isPresent(), as in "element.(by.linkText("Content")).isPresent(),  but I always get "element not found" error when I try to "click" on it as in "element(by.linkText("Content")).click()". Can you suggest why this is so?

Comment: @HiteshKapur okay, you might need to add a wait, updated the answer - please check. Thanks.

Comment: @alexce, I tried the code you provided for "wait" and now I see " Failed: Wait timed out after 5010ms" error. I even tried waiting for up to 30 seconds and even that gives the same error.